# C++ storing an abstract object in an array

Tags: c++, oop

I have been trying to pass object of an abstract class as by reference but it clearly gives error when I try to store this objects in an array of pointers with the same data type. Can anyone please explain what I'm doing wrong?
It's in the following function:

```
    void enterItem(DessertItem& item) 
    {
        if (top != (maxSize-1))
        {
            arr[top] = &item;
            top++;
        }
    }
```

The dessertItem class is actually an abstract class and "arr" is a pointer array of dessertItem so it can give reference to any new object whenever it gets passed by reference. I can't get it how am I supposed to do that?
Here's the class:

```
    class Checkout

    {

        ////Maintains a list of DessertItem references.
        protected:

        int maxSize;

        int top;

        DessertItem **arr;


    public:

    Checkout()

     {

    ///Creates a Checkout instance with an empty list of DessertItem's 


         this->maxSize=5;
         this->top=0;
         this->arr = new DessertItem*[maxSize];
         for(int i=0; i<maxSize; i++)
         {
             arr[i]=NULL;
         }
     }


     ////Clears the Checkout to begin checking out a new set of items 
    void clear()

    {

        for(int i=0; i<maxSize; i++)
         {
             arr[i]=NULL;
         }
    }


    //A DessertItem is added to the end of the list of items

    void enterItem(DessertItem &item) 

    {

        if(top!=(maxSize-1))


        {
            arr[top]=&item;
            top++;
        }
    }


     //Returns the number of DessertItem's in the list 


    int numberOfItems()

    {

        return this->top;
    }

    };
```

Comment: Please, show us the error message you're seeing.

Comment: It says expected a type specifier. What does that mean actually?

Comment: where is arr and top defined?

Comment: For this I'll have to show you the whole code. I've posted just a little snippet here which is causing the problem.

Comment: @Brainy _"For this I'll have to show you the whole code ..."_ No! Narrow it to a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) please.

Comment: I've just edited my post. Hope it helps you understand the error.

Comment: please indent the code block (select, control-k) so it gets formatted correctly.

Answer (score 1):

store your abstract objects in a `vector<unique_ptr<T>>`. when you construct them, construct them as `unique_ptr`, eg:

```
class Base {
public:
  virtual ~Base() = default;
  virtual void method() = 0;
};

class Impl : public Base {
public:
    void method() override { /* perform action here */ };
};
```

create and store like so:

```
// nasty old c-style array
std::unique_ptr<Base> a[10];
a[0] = std::move(std::unique_ptr<Base>(new Impl));

// std::vector 
std::unique_ptr<Base> p { new Impl };
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> v;

v.push_back(std::move(p));
// or
v.emplace_back(new Impl);
```

Comment: I haven't worked with vectors yet cuz I'm just a beginner. Is there any way I can sort it out without using vectors?

Comment: updated answer to demonstrate use of c-style array of unique_ptr<T>

Comment: @Brainy_ the most important rule about C++ classes like std::vector is that it is *harder* to mess them up than nasty old C-style arrays. There is ABSOLUTELY no reason to avoid them just because you're learning.

Comment: I have just indented the code and narrowed it down. Now can you please tell Is there no way I can store a child object inherited from an abstract parent class in an array of
pointers of the parent class?

Comment: you can store a *pointer* to the derived class in an array of pointers to the base class.

Comment: Thanks very much I've found the solution.